# Parameterized method chaining with DataFrame.Transform using .Net for Apache Spark

Tags: .net, apache-spark, for-loop

Could someone help me/point me to an example on how I can implement method chaining with a parameter as shown in the below scala example?
Please note the string parameter ("name") in the below example.

https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/chaining-custom-dataframe-transformations/

```
def withCat(name: String)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
df.withColumn("cats", lit(s"$name meow"))
}

val df = Seq(
"funny",
"person"
).toDF("something")

val niceDf = df
.transform(withCat("puffy"))
```

Comment: Are u able to run it or not and what is the error that you get? How someone would help you without you trying it out and showing the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi Nikunj,  just to clarify, I am trying this on  C# with .NET for Apache Spark library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.dataframe.transform?view=spark-dotnet#Microsoft_Spark_Sql_DataFrame_Transform_System_Func_Microsoft_Spark_Sql_DataFrame_Microsoft_Spark_Sql_DataFrame__), but not with Scala/Java.  I was getting a compile error like method does not accept string parameter. This could be a syntactical issue from my part as I am new to both C# and Spark.  Hope this helps and appreciate any suggestions!